# Sort a list of strings that contain integers while ignoring white space in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, sorting

I want to sort the list that has white space between each element. When I try to sort it using `sorted()`, it sorts the white space as well. I do not want that. How do I implement this in python?

```
A = '1 10'
sorted(A)
print(A)
```

> Output:

```
[' ', '0', '1', '1']
```

> Output I want:

```
'1 10'
```

Comment: Your example is as vague as it can be. Give us a better example than this. Your input is `'1 10'` and your output is `'1 10'`? Please look provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your variable A is currently a string. You want to first convert into a list, by using the split() function. The split function is used to convert a string to a list based on the given delimiter. For example,

`x=A.split(" ")` will give you a list x as ['1','10'], and then you can sort x itself using `x.sort()`, or `x=sorted(x)`. The difference between sorted and sort is sorted will return a new list, while sort sorts the given list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try the following for this.

```
string = '1 10'
final = sorted(string.split(), key = int)
final = " ".join(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` and then sort them. Use `key` parameter in `sorted`

```
A='1 10'
out=sorted(A.split(),key=int)
# ['1','10']
```

From other answers I understood you can use `join`.

```
' '.join(sorted(A.split(),key=int))
# '1 10'
```

Comment: you are missing the space between them !!

Answer (score 0):

After getting the list of numbers sorted use join to return a string with white spaces.